# Create a relationship between two nodes based on a third node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Example:

Node 1 (Case):

```
CASE_ID
123
```

Node 2 (Document):

```
DOCUMENT_ID
456
789
101
```

Node 3 (Case_to_Document):

```
CASE_ID DOCUMENT_ID UNIQUE_ID
123     456         201
123     789         202
123     101         203
```

How would I create a relationship between Document and Case in this example? I want a relationship that represents Documents 456, 789, and 101 are all related (i.e. exist WITHIN - Document-WITHIN->Case) to Case 123.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you need to start thinking more "graphically". In a graph DB, there would normally not even be a `Case_to_Document` node. One would normally create the relationships when you import the data (presumably from a relational DB), instead of afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to create unique relationships between the Case node and each of the 3 Document nodes, but where are the unique ids coming from? I'm assuming you mean to set these on the relationships, but if they can be provided in a structure along with the DOCUMENT_ID, then it should be easy:

Let's assume these are your query parameters:

```
{caseId:123, documents:[{id:456, relId:201}, {id:789, relId:202}, {id:101, relId203}]}
```

Your query then would be something like:

```
MERGE (c:Case{CASE_ID:$caseId})
UNWIND $documents as documentData
MERGE (d:Document{DOCUMENT_ID:documentData.id})
MERGE (c)<-[:WITHIN{UNIQUE_ID:documentData.relId}]-(d)
```